# Received memory warning. Level=2, Program received signal: “0”

Tags: iphone, ios4

Hi friends I am getting images from webservice and  loading these images in table view.But when i continue to scroll the program receives memory warning level1,level2 and then app exits with status 0.That happens only in device not in simulator.
Here is my code which i am putting please help me out.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *infoButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -4, 62, 30)];
    [infoButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarButtomItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarButtomItem;
    [customBarButtomItem release];
    [infoButton release];

    UIButton *homeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 62, 30)];
    [homeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"home.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [homeButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11]];
    //[homeButton setTitle:@"UPLOAD" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [homeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(homeButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtom = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:homeButton];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtom;
    [rightBarButtom release];
    [homeButton release];

    sellerTableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    sellerTableView.delegate=self;
    sellerTableView.dataSource=self;
    sellerTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    sellerTableView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    //table.separatorColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    //table.separatorColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    //[[table layer]setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
    [[sellerTableView layer]setBorderColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor]CGColor]];
    [[sellerTableView layer]setBorderWidth:2];
    //[[productTable layer]setCornerRadius:10.3F];
    [self.view addSubview:sellerTableView];

    appDel = (SnapItAppAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];



}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [[SnapItParsing sharedInstance]assignSender:self];
    [[SnapItParsing sharedInstance]startParsingForShowProducts:appDel.userIdString];
    [sellerTableView reloadData];

}


-(void)showProducts:(NSMutableArray*)proArray
{ 

    if (spinner) {
        [spinner stopAnimating];
        [spinner removeFromSuperview];
        [spinner release];
        spinner = nil;
    }


    if ([[[proArray objectAtIndex:1]objectForKey:@"Success"]isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
        //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        //self.view.alpha=.12;

        if (productInfoArray) {
            [productInfoArray release];
        }
        productInfoArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (int i=2; i<[proArray count]; i++) 
        {
            NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
            [productInfoArray addObject:[proArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            NSLog(@"data fetch array is====> /n%@",productInfoArray);
            [pool release];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark (tableview methods)

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 100;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    //return [resultarray count]; 

    return [productInfoArray count];
}


-(void)loadImagesInBackground:(NSNumber *)index{

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *frame = [[productInfoArray objectAtIndex:[index intValue]] retain];
    //NSLog(@"frame value ==>%@",[[frame objectForKey:@"Image"]length]);
    NSString *frameImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://apple.com/snapit/products/%@",[frame objectForKey:@"Image"]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:frameImagePath]];
    NSLog(@"FRAME IMAGE%d",[[frame valueForKey:@"Image" ]length]);

    if([[frame valueForKey:@"Image"] length] == 0){
        NSString *imagePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],@"no_image.png"];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
        [frame setObject:image forKey:@"friendImage"];
        [imagePath release];
        //[image release];
    }
    else {
        //NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:frameImagePath]];
        NSLog(@"image data length ==>%d",[imageData length]);
        if([imageData length] == 0){
            NSString *imagePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],@"no_image.png"];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
            [frame setObject:image forKey:@"friendImage"];
            [imagePath release];
            //[image release];
        }
        else {
            //UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [frame setObject:image forKey:@"friendImage"]; 
            //[image release];
        }
    }
    [frame release];
    frame = nil;

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTable:) withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[index intValue] inSection:0]] waitUntilDone:NO];

    [pool release];

}

-(void)reloadTable:(NSArray *)array{
    NSLog(@"array ==>%@",array);
    [sellerTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];    
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *celltype=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:celltype];


    for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        //cell.textLabel.text=[[resultarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Service"];

        /*UIImage *indicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indicator.png"];
         cell.accessoryView =
         [[[UIImageView alloc]
         initWithImage:indicatorImage]
         autorelease];*/
        /*NSThread *thread=[[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector() object:nil];
         [thread setStackSize:44];
         [thread start];*/

        cell.backgroundView=[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"]]autorelease];
        // [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]] autorelease];

        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;



    }


    UIImageView *imageView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(19, 15, 75, 68)];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    // @synchronized(self)
    //{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [productInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([dict objectForKey:@"friendImage"] == nil){
        imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        if ([dict objectForKey:@"isThreadLaunched"] == nil) {
            [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadImagesInBackground:) toTarget:self withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
            [dict setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"isThreadLaunched"];
        }
    }else {

        imageView.image =[dict objectForKey:@"friendImage"];

    }

    //NSString *imagePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],@"no_image.png"];
    //imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;//vk
    //imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    //imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    //imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    //imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;//vk
    //imageView.layer.cornerRadius=7.2f;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    //[imagePath release];
    [imageView release];

    imageView = nil;    
    //}

    UILabel *productCodeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 7, 60,20 )];
    productCodeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    productCodeLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    productCodeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Code"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:productCodeLabel];
    [productCodeLabel release];

    UILabel *CodeValueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 7, 140,20 )];
    CodeValueLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    CodeValueLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    CodeValueLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[productInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"ID"]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:CodeValueLabel];
    [CodeValueLabel release];



    UILabel *productNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 35, 60,20 )];
    productNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    productNameLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    productNameLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Name"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:productNameLabel];
    [productNameLabel release];

    UILabel *NameValueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 35, 140,20 )];
    NameValueLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NameValueLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    NameValueLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[productInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Title"]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:NameValueLabel];
    [NameValueLabel release];



    UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 68, 60,20 )];
    dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    dateLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    dateLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Date"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:dateLabel];
    [dateLabel release];

    UILabel *dateValueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 68, 140,20 )];
    dateValueLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    dateValueLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    dateValueLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[productInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"PostedDate"]];
    dateValueLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    dateValueLabel.numberOfLines=3;
    dateValueLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    [dateValueLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:dateValueLabel];
    [dateValueLabel release];

}
```

Please-2 help me out ,where i am doing mistake.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the exact same problem (running out of memory with large table lists of images). Two suggestions:

1. Use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage to cache images - it will cache to disk when you receive an memory warning automatically - freeing up images not in view, which your code don't.
2. Are your images small or large? in most cases it's wise to have a thumbnail for the table view - since it could easily be a lot of memory for just over-sized images.

Comment: Ok bro i will give it a try.Well one more thing could you let me know how to use the thumbnails for showing images in table view ,as you are suggesting this as a good way and  i think so.

Comment: Hi used the code from the github,but i am not getting the images in table view.    NSString *frameImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://apple.com/snapit/products/%@",[productInfoArray valueForKey:@"Image"]];
 
 NSLog(@"image url  %@",frameImagePath);
 
 [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:frameImagePath]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image.png"]];  Tell me where am i wrong?How to use that..Bro...

Comment: Ok I got the images bro,the url was blocked thats why,Now i will test it over iphone.Hope Everything would work well.

Comment: read the source code ;-) they are removed after a while - so you don't need to worry.

Comment: Oh is that so ,sorry dude i didn't noticed that,i need to leave at that moment.But still really thanks to you..Wish you a great luck in life bro.Could we be friends.............

Comment: Hi Magnus,i tested my app in the device i got this kind of error.Received memory warning. Level=1
(gdb) continue
(gdb) continue
2011-01-11 12:33:19.440 SnapItApp[2114:307] usertype memory warning received
Tue Jan 11 12:33:21 iPhone SnapItApp[2114] <Error>: Could not write any more data to the consumer.Why thats still happening.

Comment: Hey Magnus could you help me please why thats still happening with me.......my app is exiting again and receiving memory warning 1,2... please-2 let me know..

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing particularly mysterious going on here. You get a memory warning, which you ignore. Then it sends you another warning, which you also ignore. Then it force-quits your app.

In short: you're using too much memory.

You need to figure out a way to use less, perhaps by saving the image files to "disk" and only bring those you're trying to display into memory, or by using fewer images or smaller images. I'm sure there are lots of other ways you can think of but without knowing what your app does it's difficult to be more specific.

Comment: Yes Stephen you are right bro there is some memory problem ,but I am unable to figure it out.I even took the view controllers locally.What i am doing here i just uploaded some images to the server and then fetching these images in a table view.But when i continue to scroll the table view the app Exits.Hey Stephen give me some idea what should i do dear..I am gonna crazy have wasted my 2 days changed the code even but nothing happened.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that there's a leak but I don't think that's the case (at least on a quick look I don't see anything obvious). I think you are just using too much memory. I would suggest you use Instruments to measure how much memory you're using and where. Then you can optimise your code, or fix the leaks if there are any. I don't think there's a silver bullet here.